# Can ffmpeg parse from a specific position in a file?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-streaming, video-processing, mediainfo

I am uploading a video using a form and want to parse the video info from a uploaded temporary file. The temporary file contains some form information at the start of the file and the remain is video bytes. Can ffmpeg parse the file from the position where the video bytes start?How? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just looking to script together pieces probably the easiest approach is to use the `dd(1)` tool to extract only the data you're interested in. It would look something like this:

```
dd if=/path/to/temp/file ibs=<size to skip> skip=1 | ffmpeg --whatever
```

It won't be *perfect*, since it'll use that block size for *all* input operations; something larger and a multiple of a power of two would be ideal compared to however much space you're wasting at the beginning, but it ought to be better enough than creating a new file with nearly identical contents.

Comment: I have tried that and don't like that way. Thank you all the same.

Comment: I only found this way at present and found it useful. Can you tell me how many bytes ffmpeg need to determine the video format? Or how many bytes is enough to describe the video information for various video formats so I can extract certain bytes using dd rather than extract all from the original file.Thanks!

Comment: The `libmagic` library is able to determine file formats from the first kilobyte or so of contents -- so once you strip off your header, you'll probably be able to discover the file type with an additional kilobyte of data, tops. (Most _containers_ will tell you their type in a few bytes, but discovering the formats of the streams inside the containers may take quite a bit more.)

Answer (score 4):

Try the `-skip_initial_bytes <bytecount>` parameter.

http://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/1909

Comment: I suppose, this answer must be marked as a solution